# Will local variables be independent in recursively called Lotusscript function?

Tags: recursion, lotus-domino, lotusscript

If I have a recursive function (Lotusscript) and inside the function is a locally declared variable, will each iteration of the call keep the variables independently stored in memory?

For example, I have a counter on a main function that loops 10 times....it calls the recursive function, and in certain circumstances, that will call itself....but passing a different object each time as an argument.  The recursive function has its own counter variable declared locally.

Suppose this main function if called, and it calls the recursive function one time, and begins a loop, counting up to ten itself.   On the 5th loop, it calls itself.   This recursion will end due to setting a global boolean, and now I have three known local variables, the main function, and two from the recursive function.

Will each of these counters be kept track of independently, so that depending on which function I am in it knows where it is in its own ten loops?

I hope I made this clear.   I am trying a simple proof-of-concept function but it is really confusing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will be independant: the local variables are local to each call within the recursion as long as you don‘t use them as parameters as they are byref by default:

```
Sub RecurseMe( intParameter as Integer )
   Dim intCount as Integer
   Print "Called with:", intParameter
   intParameter = intParameter + 1
   intCount = intCount + 1
   Print "IntCount: ", intCount
   If intParameter < 3 then
      Call RecurseMe( intParameter )
   End If
   Print "Exiting with: ", intParameter
End Sub

Dim intTest as Integer
intTest = 1
Call RecurseMe( intTest )
Print "Final result: ", intTest
```

Will output:

> Called with: 1
>   IntCount: 1
>   Called with: 2
>   IntCount: 1
>   Exiting with: 3
>   Exiting with: 3
>   Finale result: 3

As your see: intCount is always reinitialised in sub, intParameter will even be changed in the calling sub.